# Moving Cursor Position in Kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive

I have difficulties moving the cursor to a certain clip position in Kdenlive.

I demonstrated the issue in [this short screencast](https://youtu.be/O2RJW0dFyUc) and reported it as the [following bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=364214).

Is anyone affected by the same problem?

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce this problem (maybe because I'm using an older version ?). But I'd try to save the project and close and reopen kdenlive, maybe it's some kind of glitch. FYI, the "guides" as well as the blue thing which you can move around (and which is set by the "set zone start / end" buttons) can be used as "markers" to mark certain sections (eg. to come back to them later, or to help align clips, or to play the same section over and over while adjusting something).

Comment: Thank you Jonas! I think I will report this as a bug. Restarting Kdenlive doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Maybe add a link to your bug report to your question, too. Some more ideas: does the problem go away with a new project ? Maybe deleting the Kdenlive preferences / data is an option ? Perhaps the old ones which you backed up (?) are not compatible with the new version ?

Comment: Good idea. I updated my question. A new project has the same problem. Deleting `~/.config/kdenliverc`, however, did resolve the problem. But I still don't know what exactly caused the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the exact same issue. The cursor was somehow stuck at the beginning of the video while using kdenlive. 
I tried the fix mentioned here to delete the ~/.config/kdenliverc file, but in fact I couldn't find such a file in my system.

I could not even find a .kdenlive directory in my home folder as suggested on other forums.

Finally what solved the problem for me was switching to the Project Monitor instead of the Clip monitor in kdenlive. I have no idea how I switched to the Clip monitor in kdenlive, but when I switched back to the Project Monitor, the cursor was again movable.

Comment: The menu is *Monitor* | *Switch monitor*.  `T` is a keyboard shortcut.